# create a list which joins each entry of second list and stores it (python)

Tags: python, list, data-structures

What's the best way to create a list of list which has each value of the first list corresponding to the second list?
Like:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[5,6,7]
```

create c such that:

```
c=[[1,5][1,6][1,7][2,5][2,6][2,7][3,5][3,6][3,7]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to use `itertools` library.

```
import itertools
a=[1,2,3]
b=[5,6,7]
c=list(itertools.product(a,b))
```

But it makes a list of tuples. If you specifically need a list of lists, you can do

```
c=[[x, y] for x in a for y in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [5, 6, 7]
c = [list(i) for i in product(a, b)]
```

**Value of c:**

```
  [[1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7]]
```

**itertools.product - From the docs:**

> Init signature: itertools.product(self, /, *args, **kwargs) Docstring:
> product(*iterables, repeat=1) --> product object
>
> Cartesian product of input iterables.  Equivalent to nested for-loops.
>
> For example, product(A, B) returns the same as:  ((x,y) for x in A for
> y in B). The leftmost iterators are in the outermost for-loop, so the
> output tuples cycle in a manner similar to an odometer (with the
> rightmost element changing on every iteration).
>
> To compute the product of an iterable with itself, specify the number
> of repetitions with the optional repeat keyword argument. For example,
> product(A, repeat=4) means the same as product(A, A, A, A).
>
> product('ab', range(3)) --> ('a',0) ('a',1) ('a',2) ('b',0) ('b',1)
> ('b',2) product((0,1), (0,1), (0,1)) --> (0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,1,0)
> (0,1,1) (1,0,0) ...
>
> Type:           type

This solution makes use of a [list comprehension](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+list+comprehension+tutorial&atb=v19&ia=web)